# How to lock a python variable file in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I need to store my user id and password in a python variable file in robot framework. This credential will be utilized to login to website to test it. No other person should be able to view my credential (even in git also). Hence, I have to lock this variable file. Is there any way to lock this python variable file?

Comment: What do you main by 'variable file'? Simply a Python file with some global variables?

Comment: Yes. For example: Credential.py  is  a file which will contain   UserID="Dhinesh",
Password="1234"

Comment: https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt may be this can be little help

Answer (score 0):

Due to their nature Source Code Repository systems are public in nature. So, either you lock the repository or it's open to everyone. This makes storing any type of sensitive data in such a system a bad idea.

For these types of information it is typically best to have a separate file and refer to that file when executing the run. In Robot Framework this can be done using [Variable files](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variable-files). These can be referred to using the `Variables    myvariables.<ext>`. There is support for Python and YAML files.

Securing these files can be as easy as placing them in a location that only few can access to setting up tools to store them encrypted and only make them available when having the right key. This is a separate topic on it's own with it's own challenges.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But, the difficulty itself raises on locking the variable file as I don't know how to do that. Need assistance on this part.

Comment: Please be more specific about what it is about the variable file approach you don't understand. Please follow the link to the documentation, it describes the different options. Keep in mind that this type of information should be considered execution configuration and not be part of any code base.